# Как передать параметры в CBV-представления

Tags: python, django

Привет всем! 
Хочу перейти с FBV на CBV, но не пойму, как правильно передать параметры в класс.
Например в fbv я делал так:

```
url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/main', views.Man, name='man'),
```

и в представлении:

```
def Man(request, user_id):
```

И потом могу использовать user_id для своих нужд. Как аналогичное сделать на cbv? 
Что-то поиск туго идет на эту тему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект запроса в методах CVB можно получить из одноимённого атрибута - `self.request`, позиционные аргументы из списка `self.args`, а именованные из словаря `self.kwargs`:

```
class ManView(DetailView):
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        request = self.request
        user_id = self.kwargs.get('user_id')
        ...
```